# Select objects within an area using d3

Tags: graph, d3.js, data-visualization

I am currently creating a tool which displays graphs and then I want to perform statistical analysis on a select set of nodes in each graph.

[image]

Is there a way to detect which nodes are contained by the red area (see image) using d3.js. I understand I could use the coordinates for the rectangle as draw but I would like to implement more arbitary shapes.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/5020993)?